# ngx-file-drop Subida de archivos y botón de añadir archivos

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenía un par de dudas con el plugin ngx-file-drop el problema que tengo es que yo quiero poner un texto que se llama navega y al hacer click abrir la ventana de navegación de archivos para buscar los archivos que deseo subir. En la documentación hay una cosa parecida pero es para poner un botón

`[showBrowseBtn]="true"`

Pero claro a mi eso no me sirve yo quiero ponerlo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego también vienen estas líneas de código comentadas que es para programar la subida de los archivos pero no las entiendo bien, a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano

```
public files: UploadFile[] = [];
public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
this.files = event.files;
for (const droppedFile of event.files) {

  // Is it a file?
  if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
    const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
    fileEntry.file((file: File) => {

      // Here you can access the real file
      console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, file);

      /**
      // You could upload it like this:
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('logo', file, relativePath)

      // Headers
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'security-token': 'mytoken'
      })

      this.http.post('https://mybackend.com/api/upload/sanitize-and-save-logo', formData, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe(data => {
        // Sanitized logo returned from backend
      })
      **/

    });
  } else {
    // It was a directory (empty directories are added, otherwise only files)
    const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
    console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, fileEntry);
  }
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que con ngx-file-drop lo único que puedes usar es [showBrowseBtn]="true", lo que si puedes es darle estilo al botón y poner el texto que quieras en el con las propiedades: browseBtnClassName y browseBtnLabel

Comment: Para ponerlo así como en tu imagen tienes que usar la api drag and drop de html5 aunque no se como combinarlo con angular.

Answer (score 1):

**I. Customización del layout.**

Para hacer lo que vos querés hay que reemplazar el `ng-template` que muestra el botón por uno customizado.

Si bien hay un indicio de que el componente lo permite porque está escrito literalmente, me parece que se olvidaron de documentar como se hace.

Para ver como se hace hay que recurir al [github](https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop) del mismo.

En el *ngx-file-drop.component.html*:

```
...
<ng-template #defaultContentTemplate>
      <div *ngIf="dropZoneLabel" class="ngx-file-drop__drop-zone-label">{{dropZoneLabel}}</div>
      <div *ngIf="showBrowseBtn">
        <input type="button" [className]="browseBtnClassName" value="{{browseBtnLabel}}" (click)="openFileSelector($event)" />
      </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="contentTemplate || defaultContentTemplate"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ openFileSelector: openFileSelector }">
</ng-template>
...
```

Vemos que si existe un `contentTemplate` se usará éste antes que `defaultContentTemplate` que forma parte del componente y que muestra el boton.

Y en *ngx-file-drop.component.ts* vemos que `contentTemplate` se setea usando la directiva `NgxFileDropContentTemplateDirective` sobre el template customizado, que a su vez forma parte del contenido del componente.

```
// custom templates
@ContentChild(NgxFileDropContentTemplateDirective, { read: TemplateRef, static: false }) contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Entonces el `ng-template` redefinido para que sea asignado a `contentTemplate` queda como:

```
<ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp>
    <span>Arrastrar archivos aqu&iacute; o&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" class="btnNavega" (click)="openFileSelector($event)">NAVEGA</a>&nbsp;
    <span> para subirlos.</span>
</ng-template>
```

Nota: En la solución original usando el `Button` se invocaba la función para abrir el selector de archivos usando un `let-<variable>="funcion"`. Esto no anduvo cuando reemplacé el botón con un `<a>`.

Para solucionarlo setié el `ngx-file-drop` como un `@childView` del componente y de esta forma poder llamar a la función desde Typescript.

```
  <ngx-file-drop #fileDrop (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)"
  (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)" (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)">
      <ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp>
            <span>Arrastrar archivos aqu&iacute; o&nbsp;</span>  <a href="#" class="btnNavega" (click)="openFileSelector($event)">NAVEGA</a>&nbsp;<span> para subirlos.</span>
      </ng-template>
  </ngx-file-drop>
```

Y en el *.ts* del componente:

```
@ViewChild('fileDrop') fileDrop: NgxFileDropComponent;
...
openFileSelector($event){
    this.fileDrop.openFileSelector($event);
}
```

**CSS para el botón:**

```
.btnNavega{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0782d0;
}
.btnNavega:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**II. Código comentado para el envío de los archivos.**

El código comentado corresponde al envío del archivo usando la api de [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData). FormData permite agregar el archivo como parte de un Request multipart (Similar a un e-mial que tiene texto, y archivos adjuntos).

En el ejemplo `logo` es el nombre del parámetro (en un formulario sería el "name"), file es el objeto [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File) que describe al archivo y que se obtiene del elemento `<input type="file">` a través del `ngx-file-drop`, y `relativepath` es el nombre con el que viaja archivo.

Luego el ejemplo asume que necesitas enviar un token de autorización en un header, presumiblemente para mantener la sisión o para validar permisos otorgados con anterioridad.

El `POST` enviado de esta forma va a efectuarse con `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data`.

Vale aclarar que en el ejemplo se envían de a un archivo a la vez. Pero al ser el Request un multipart, bien se podría hacer un solo Request con todos los archivos juntos.
Para esto, todos los archivos deberían appendearse al mismo objeto FormData antes de hacer el post.